# Android Encountered unknown AudioTrack event 5 for CAudioPlayer

Tags: android, audiotrack, opensl

I'm using OpenSL to play sounds on Android.
I keep getting this Error : Encountered unknown AudioTrack event 5 for CAudioPlayer.
According to android_AudioPlayer.cpp, this shouldn't happen, since the value 5 (EVENT_BUFFER_END) is not treated as an error.
I use Android 4.1.1.